# How does someone who is blind interact with a website that has infographics?

Tags: web-development, accessibility

I understand that there are some technologies that exist (text to speech, or that thing whistler had in Sneakers) that could enable someone that does not have sight to understand what is on a webpage.  If the webpage has raster images (like an infographic - text in a graphic) how is that navigated/read?  Is there a standard that I can look at to accommodate someone that cannot see?

Could you conceivably put a link to an audio file in AltText?  This way you could narrate something yourself?

Comment: I'd guess clever use of alternate text would do the trick

Comment: That's a LOT of Alt Text.  I'm more looking to see if any other standard exists, maybe a link to an audio file...

Comment: There seems to be a project that might do what you need: http://www.accessibleinfographics.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a project that might do what you need: http://www.accessibleinfographics.com/

> What's This Whole TIKISI Thing?
>
> TIKISI is the name of the system we're
> working on to give blind and low vision users access to graphical
> information. It currently supports multitouch input, keyboard input,
> and speech input. For output, TIKISI supports visual and speech
> output, and we're very interested in working on Braille output as
> well; for example, to bluetooth braille displays, but this depends on
> what platform TIKISI is run on e.g. IOS, Android, Desktop, etc.